# PostgreSQL: update table with new records from the same table on remote server

Tags: django, postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL server running in production and a plenty of workstations with an isolated development environments. Each one has its own local PostgreSQL server (with no replication with the production server). Developers need to receive updates stored in production server periodically.

I am trying to figure out how to dump the contents of several selected tables from server in order to update the tables on development workstations. The biggest challenge is that the tables I'm trying to synchronize may be *diverged* (developers may add - but not delete - new fields to the tables through the Django ORM, while schema of the production database remains unchanged for a long time).

[image]

Therefore the updated records and new fields of the tables stored on workstations *must be* preserved against the overwriting.

I guess that direct dumps (e.g. `pg_dump -U remote_user -h remote_server -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db`) are not suitable here.

**UPD**: If possible I would also like to avoid the use of third (intermediate) database while transferring the data from production database to the workstations.

Comment: You'll probably be writing your own trigger-based replication solution for this, or heavily modifying one like Londiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach.

I'll outline example based on a single table `customer`.

1. We want to copy some entries from this table on production. Obviously, full table dump will break new stuff that exists on development envs;
2. Therefore, create a table with the similar structure, but a different name, say `customer_$`. Another way is to create a dedicated schema for such “copying” tables. You might also want to include a couple of extra columns there, like `copy_id` and/or `copy_stamp`;
3. Now you can `INSERT INTO customer_$ SELECT ...` to populate your copying table with wanted data. You might need to think of the way how to do this, though. In the tool we use here we can supply predicate data via the `-w` switch, like `-w "customer_id IN (SELECT id FROM cust2copy)"`;
4. After you've populated your copying table(s), you can dump them. Make sure to use the following switches to the `pg_dump`:

   - `--column-inserts` to explicitly list target columns, for on development env copying table might have changed it's structure. This might be “slow” for big volumes though;
   - `--table / -t` to specify tables to dump.
5. On the target env, make sure to (1) empty copying tables and (2) prevent parallel activities of similar nature;
6. Load date into the copying tables;
7. The most interesting part comes: you need to check, that data you're bout to `INSERT` into the main tables will not conflict with any of the constraints defined on the tables. You might have:

   - `PRIMARY KEY` violations. You can (1) replace existing entries or (2) merge entries together or (3) skip entries from the copying tables or (4) choose to assign different `ID` in the copying tables;
   - `UNIQUE KEY` violations, most likely you'll have to `UPDATE` some columns in the copying tables;
   - `FOREIGN KEY` violations, you'll have either to give up on such entries, or to copy over missing stuff from the production as well;
   - `CHECK` violations, you'll have to investigate this ones manually.
8. After checks are done and data in the copying tables is fixed, you can copy it into the main tables.

This is a very formal description of the approach. Say, for step `#7` we have a huge pile of extra tools to do ID or ID ranges remapping, to manipulate data in the copying tables, adjusting security settings, ownership, some defaults, etc.

Also, we have a so-called catalogue for this tool, which allows us to group logically tied tables under common names. Say, to copy customers from production we have to check round 50 tables in order to satisfy all possible dependencies.

I haven't seen similar tools in the wild though so far.